# Unable to login to gnome session after upgrading to 17.10

Tags: unity, nvidia, gnome, login, 17.10

I just upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10, when logging in, I have three options:

- Unity
- Ubuntu on Xorg
- GNOME on Xorg

However, I can only login using unity, the other two options make the screen turn black and then it goes back to the login screen.

I haven't been able to find much information on this issue, however, I think it may be related to my laptop having a Nvidia graphics card. Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well if black screens are Wayland based then for sure Nvidia is cause. it is just not compatible.  You need install X11 versions of other desktops.

Also We see similar when login session is corrupted or not compatible with new programs.  One good test is to create new user account. If it works, it is evidence that session for old user account has bad settings. Can clean out ~/.cache to fix